# Table to pandas is killing my session in azure Synapse

Tags: pandas, azure-synapse

I am calling a table from a database into synapse in the form of a table. Then my next step is to transform into pandas so that i can run all the codes related to pandas.However when i convert the table to pandas, the session gets killed. I have gone through transforming to parquet file, however i am not able to convert to parquet from a table and then read as pandas data frame. Is there any best practice for this:

```
%pyspark
rawdata = spark.sql("""select Invoice_Flag,
Vendor_Name,Market,
Inv_Age,Inv_Amount_In_GC,
Inv_Early_Late_Flag
FROM default.Regression_copy where Market='India'""")

%%pyspark
model_data= rawdata.select("*").toPandas()
```

It is in this transformation to pandas the session gets killed may be because of huge datasize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The databricks optimized pandas package is named koalas, so I would try databricks.koalas (`install databricks.koalas as ks`) and convert to a koalas dataframe with `ks.DataFrame(rawdata)`.